# Tableview Integer sorting bugged?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview and one of my columns consist of Integer values:

- 1
- 444
  -9

If I sort on this column, I would expect 444 to be the "highest" number and therefor be the first row, but JavaFX believes 9 is higher?

Any tips?

MVCE:

```
public class TableViewTEST extends Application {

private TableView table = new TableView();
final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("1", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person("9", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person("444", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com")

);

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    table.getItems().addAll(data);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    stage.setTitle(
            "Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(
            300);
    stage.setHeight(
            500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");

    label.setFont(
            new Font("Arial", 20));

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First");
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");

    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName")
    );
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName")
    );
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email")
    );

    table.getColumns()
            .addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();

    vbox.setSpacing(
            5);
    vbox.setPadding(
            new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren()
            .addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

*Edit*

Okay, I have found out the reason for this is because I use String in the model.. So the updated question is, how can you create a new sorting functionality on the table column so that it sorts as integer even though there's string in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your values are `String`s, so they are sorted lexicographically; since the character '4' comes before the character '9', '444' comes before '9'.

If you make those fields integer fields, then they will be sorted numerically. It's helpful here to use properly typed `TableView`s and `TableColumn`s, instead of raw types.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSortTest extends Application {

private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person(1, "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person(9, "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person(444, "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com")

);

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    table.getItems().addAll(data);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    stage.setTitle(
            "Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(
            300);
    stage.setHeight(
            500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");

    label.setFont(
            new Font("Arial", 20));

    TableColumn<Person, Integer> idCol = new TableColumn<>("Id");
    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");

    idCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("id")
    );
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name")
    );
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email")
    );

    table.getColumns()
            .addAll(idCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();

    vbox.setSpacing(
            5);
    vbox.setPadding(
            new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren()
            .addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

public static class Person {
    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id");
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");

    public Person(int id, String name, String email) {
        this.id.set(id);
        this.name.set(name);
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return this.idProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setId(final int id) {
        this.idProperty().set(id);
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
        return this.emailProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
        this.emailProperty().set(email);
    }


}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: The only problem is that I never know what kind of columns the user adds, so I use   col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());

                }
            }); to add them dynamically

Comment: Then your column doesn't consist of integer values, it consists of string values. You would need to implement some logic to determine the type and add the correct type of column.

Comment: Thanks.. Do you know if it's possible to have an code like in the comment above, but with integers instead?

Comment: Replace `String` with `Integer`, and `return new SimpleIntegerProperty(Integer.parseInt(param.getValue().get(j).toString()));`. This assumes all items in the column are valid integer representations.

Comment: I tried that, but then I get "SimpleIntegerProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>"

Comment: Actually found out that just before you posted. Thanks James, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `Comparator`:

```
firstNameCol.setComparator(new CustomComparator());
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you have a `String` type in your column, as it was originally posted, and you want to sort it numerically trying to parse all the strings, and in case there'are some non-integer strings, sort these lexicographically, this will be a valid `Comparator`:

```
private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
        if (o1 == null) return -1;
        if (o2 == null) return 1;

        Integer i1=null;
        try{ i1=Integer.valueOf(o1); } catch(NumberFormatException ignored){}
        Integer i2=null;
        try{ i2=Integer.valueOf(o2); } catch(NumberFormatException ignored){}

        if(i1==null && i2==null) return o1.compareTo(o2);
        if(i1==null) return -1;
        if(i2==null) return 1;

        return i1-i2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would fail horribly with some sets of strings, because it's not well-ordered: e.g. "1a", "2", and "12" (which is the first item?).

Comment: For sure it will be better to define the type of column before creating the table, so one can benefit of the default sorting mechanism for each type, without "slow" parsing. But since the OP didn't provide more details in this question, I just come up with a simple solution. I take it's not a complete solution for every possible situation, as that should be a task for the OP, once he know the type of data he has to deal with.

Comment: It's not that the parsing is slow, but the problem is that the sort algorithm isn't guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: @James_D I take my code misses some null checkings, and some possible cases like you mentioned, where not all the data can be parsed. But what will you do in case you have a column with `String` type and want to try to sort it using different comparators? Check that all the data is parseable, before installing the comparator? What is the `setComparator()` method for, then?

Comment: `setComparator` allows you to change the definition of the ordering: e.g. you could sort strings ignoring case. But you still have to provide a valid ordering: i.e. something that conforms to the contract of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Your comparator would work under some additional assumptions - e.g. that you knew all `String`s would parse to `int`s - but if you can make those assumptions there are better ways to do it. If you can't make those assumptions you need a comparator that works without them.

Comment: e.g. you could define a comparator that placed all integers first, ordered numerically, then all non-integer strings, ordered lexicographically - that would conform to the contract defined by `Comparator`.

Comment: @James_D Ok, thanks. I've edited my answer. Will this be conform with the contract defined by `Comparator`?

Comment: Yes, that works... you can fairly easily prove that if o1 < o2 < o3 then o1 < o3 (just a few cases to work through), and similarly that o1 < o2 => o2 > o1. If you needed a high-performance variant you'd probably want to avoid using the try-catch as a test, but you know that already...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65385/discussion-between-jose-pereda-and-james-d).

Comment: Upvote for pointing out the comparator option, which solves other related problems where integer comparison isn't sufficient.